# Bootstrap with grid layout gets unnecessary spacing in 3 columns

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I'm using a `react-bootstrap` package on my project,

I have a 3 `<Col>` component like this

```js
<Container>
    <Row>
        <Col xs={12} lg={7}> {/* A */}
            ....
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} lg={5}> {/* B */}
            ...
        </Col>
        <Col xs={12} lg={7}> {/* C */}
            ...
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Container>
```

That makes the output in `LG` screen similar to this

```
_______ _______
|     | |     |
|  A  | |  B  |
|_____| |_____|
|     |
|  C  |
|_____|
```

That output was okay, but the problem here is when the `B` component gets larger height, it will give a unnecessary spacing between `Col A` and `Col C` like this

```
_______ _______
|     | |     |
|  A  | |     |
|_____| |  B  |
        |     |
        |_____|
_______  
|     |
|  C  |
|_____|
```

I don't want to move my `C` lower when the `B` gets taller in `lg` grid, what should I do?

Comment: See [masonry](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/masonry/)

Comment: Hi @Spikatrix, I'll try to understand it, but can you give a sample use of masonry on my given code snippet? I tried to use it, it works well in lg screen, but in xs, some of the components gets left behind floating at my other components, in short, something went wrong when I use it in small screen size, a sample code of use of it without issue will really help and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for Masonry CSS grid.
On the masonry axis, rather than sticking to a strict grid with gaps being left after shorter items, the items in the following row rise up to completely fill the gaps.

```
_______ _______
|     | |     |
|  A  | |     |
|_____| |  B  |
_______ |     |
|     | |_____|
|  C  | _______
|_____| |     |
        |  D  |
        |_____|
```

Here some links how to implement Masonry layout to your sites.

For Firefox: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout#:~:text=Masonry%20layout%20is%20a%20layout,to%20completely%20fill%20the%20gaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout#:%7E:text=Masonry%20layout%20is%20a%20layout,to%20completely%20fill%20the%20gaps).

For other browsers: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged in Stack Overflow. Please include the relevant parts of the link in your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Masonry layout

[Bootstrap Masonry](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/masonry/)

It works by covering vertical spaces left by uneven same-row columns.

Comment: but how can I use it on my current setup?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just Wrote a Pseudocode. Hope It Helps

```
<Container>
    <Row>
        <Col xs={6} lg={6}> {/* COLUMN 1 */}
              <Col xs={12} lg={12}> {/* A */}
              ...
              </Col>
              <Col xs={12} lg={12}> {/* C */}
              ...
              </Col>
        </Col>

        <Col xs={6} lg={6}> {/* COLUMN 2 */}
            <Col xs={12} lg={12}> {/* B */}
             ...
            </Col>
        </Col>      
    </Row>
</Container>
```

Comment: If I do this, the grid won't be aligned for the smaller screen.
it's going to be
a
c
b 
instead of 
a
b
c